# GTK changing background image of window

Tags: image, background, gtk

how can I achieve it? I was searching for it for like 30 minutes and found examples which don't work or work in bad way. I simply want to change background image of window without changing bakgrounds of other dialogs windows etc? But I want buttons and labels to be transparent on that background.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gtk drawing set background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150706/gtk-drawing-set-background-image)

Answer (score 5):

I found a python example that worked for me at:

http://islascruz.org/html/index.php/blog/show/Image-as-background-in-a-Gtk-Application..html

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gtk

def draw_pixbuf(widget, event):
        path = '/home/markuz/wallpapers/WMwall1024x768.gif'
        pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(path)
        widget.window.draw_pixbuf(widget.style.bg_gc[gtk.STATE_NORMAL], pixbuf, 0, 0, 0,0)

window = gtk.Window()
window.set_title('Drawing Test')
window.set_size_request(640,480)
window.connect('destroy',gtk.main_quit)
hbbox = gtk.HButtonBox()
window.add(hbbox)
hbbox.connect('expose-event', draw_pixbuf)
button = gtk.Button('Press Me!')
hbbox.pack_start(button, True, False, 10)
window.show_all()

gtk.main()
```

I also found a C example at:

http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?t=446

**Code**

```
GtkWidget *SetupWindow(gchar *data,gboolean Transient)
{
    GdkPixmap *background;
    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;
    GdkScreen *ourscreen;
    GdkColormap *colormap;
    GtkStyle *style;
    GdkColor fg;
    GdkColor bg;
    GError *error = NULL;
    GdkRectangle *rect;
    GtkWidget *window;

    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file ("pics/fb.png",&error);
    if (error != NULL) {
        if (error->domain == GDK_PIXBUF_ERROR) {
            g_print ("Pixbuf Related Error:\n");
        }
        if (error->domain == G_FILE_ERROR) {
            g_print ("File Error: Check file permissions and state:\n");
        }

        g_printerr ("%s\n", error[0].message);
        exit(1);
    }
    gdk_pixbuf_render_pixmap_and_mask (pixbuf, &background, NULL, 0);
    style = gtk_style_new ();
    style->bg_pixmap[0] = background;
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), data);
    // gtk_window_maximize(GTK_WINDOW(window));
    gtk_window_set_modal (GTK_WINDOW (window),TRUE);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window),640,480);
    gtk_widget_set_style (GTK_WIDGET(window), GTK_STYLE(style));
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window),GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 14);
    if(Transient==TRUE)
    gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW (window),GTK_WINDOW(mainwindow));
    gtk_widget_show (window);
    return(window);
}
```

But I didn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

It works!

```
import re,os, time, socket, datetime, threading, subprocess, fileinput, gobject, gst, gtk, logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='/var/tmp/log.log',level=logging.DEBUG)

gobject.threads_init()

def thread1(s):
  logging.debug("uploading")
  os.system("""/var/tmp/upload.download.largest.sh %s %s &""" % (s[1], s[2]) )

class server(object):
  def __init__(self):

    button_rc = """
    pixmap_path "/var/tmp"

    # 1) Background > Image > change the logo.png
    style "window" {
      bg_pixmap[NORMAL] = "logo.png"
    }
    # imports
    widget_class "GtkWindow" style "window"
    """

    """ Window """
    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    self.window.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.Color(6400, 6400, 6440))
    self.window.set_size_request(1280, 720)
    self.window.set_border_width(1)
    self.window.set_decorated(False)
    self.window.set_title("server")
    self.window.move(0,0)
    self.window.set_name("main window")

    gtk.rc_parse_string(button_rc) # 2) important line for the background image

    self.window.connect("delete-event", gtk.main_quit)
    self.window.connect ('button-press-event',self.callback)
    self.window.set_events(gtk.gdk.EXPOSURE_MASK | gtk.gdk.LEAVE_NOTIFY_MASK | gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | gtk.gdk.POINTER_MOTION_MASK| gtk.gdk.POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK )
    self.window.show_all()
    self.window.set_keep_above(True)
    if(self.window.get_window().get_state() == gtk.gdk.WINDOW_STATE_MAXIMIZED):
      self.window.unmaximize()

  def callback(self):
    logging.debug("uploading")
  def quit(self, window):
    gtk.main_quit()

  def run(self):
    gtk.main()

if __name__=='__main__':
  t = server()
  t.run()
```